# automount with curlftpfs

Tags: fstab, automount

i would like to automount my backuftp with curlftpfs, i added

```
curlftpfs#<serverip> /backup/backupftp fuse allow_other,uid=0,gid=0,umask=0022 0 0
```

in /etc/fstab

and put the login details in /root/.netrc

```
mount -a
```

works but when i reboot the backupftp doesn't get mounted, i've got the same config on another machine where it does work.

dmesg doesn't show any errors, how can i debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
curlftpfs#<serverip> /backup/backupftp fuse allow_other,uid=0,gid=0,umask=0022,_netdev 0 0
```

`_netdev` requires network to be available before the mount, which is my suspicion why it isn't working.

Comment: i tried it but without success, still doesn't get mounted.

Comment: Same issue, what now?

Comment: If you can `mount -a` successfully, copy the line from /etc/mtab to /etc/fstab which corresponds to the mount you want.